# how to change just the year part of a vb.net date

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can i change just the year part of a date?

so if a user selects 3/10/2009
i want current to equal 3/10/2011

```
 Dim current1 As Date
    current1 = TextBox1.Text
    current1.Year = Now.Year
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
date1 = DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text)

current1 = new Date(Now.Year, date1.Month, date1.Day)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can probably do

```
current1 = current1.AddYears(2)
```

But you probably cannot do

```
current1 = TextBox1.Text
```

In order to parse a date from a string, you have to do this

```
current1 = DateTime.Parse(TextBox.Text)
```